# Findstr, how to read part of string/line

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, output, findstr

I have file with a list of names and extensions, formatted such as below each on it's own line:

> JoeBloggs=102
>
> JohnSmith=109

What I want to do is use findstr but read the number after the equals sign. So I am using the following command:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /p %username% extensions.txt') do set ext=%%a
```

If a user logs on as JoeBloggs it will capture `JoeBloggs=102`, what I want it to do is only capture `102`. So essentially only the numbers after the equals sign.

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%a in (names.txt) do (
if "%%a"=="%username%" set ext=%%b
)
echo %ext%
pause >nul
```

This will read each line of your text file and split it when it comes across an `=` sign.

I have specified to use tokens 1 and 2, 1 being before the split, and 2 being after so we can compare the first and if it's what you want, use the second.

Comment: With a small explanation it would be perfect :-)

Comment: Thanks jeb, I will add one now :)